# Angular - Hide a button when clicking without using ng-show or ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to hide a button in my form, once it's submitted and everything is working fine, I need to hide it and show something else, is there a way to do in my controller:

```
this.show= false;
```

Or do I need to add ng-show to the button and implement a variable to set to hide it?

Comment: you could use `ng-if` there like `ng-if="vm.show"`. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding new variables, why not using what is already designed for that. In the angular object representing your form, there is a `$submitted` property. 
Therefore, providing your form is named *myForm*, something like that should do the trick:

```
<button ng-if="!myForm.$submitted">Button</button>
```

See **[official guide about forms in angular](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/guide/forms)**

Answer (score 2):

You could use ng-class:

```
ng-class="{'some-class': !some.object.user, 'some-other-class': some.object.user}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be to use ng-style to do the job:

Comment: ng-style you would need to add style to .css file and use extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
$scope.condition = true;
$scode.activeCondition = function (con) {
    $scope.condition = !con;
};
```

in html

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{'active': condition}" ng-click="activeCondition(condition)">
```